# Jquery - Input who deligate names which auto detect and are then previewed within an option list

Tags: jquery

I have a question here and its pretty specific and challenging.

Pretty much i have an online form which the user has to put in their name as well as a delegate. Which means documented in the form will be two seperate names. first_name, last_name, first_name1, last_name1.

Im trying to make it so it picks up these two names and places them in an option list. so they can select who the priority deligate is out of those two names. both first name and last name.

Wo it would look like this.

first_name (field)

last_name (field)

first_name1 (field)

first_name1 (field)

Then in the options list, to be previewed like this.

```
<select>
<option>first_name last_name</option>
</option>first_name1 last_name1</option>
</select>
```

If anyone could help that would be great!

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest implementation: a jQuery "change" event which alters the contents of the select options any time a text field changes. The event is dynamically attached to any input with a class of "name" (id, name and class values can be changed to whatever makes the most sense for your application, so long as the corresponding Javascript is changed also).

HTML:

```
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" class="name" />
<input id="last_name" name="last_name" class="name" />
<input id="first_name1" name="first_name1" class="name" />
<input id="last_name1" name="last_name1" class="name" />

<select id="priority">
    <option value="1"></option>
    <option value="2"></option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$("input.name").live("change", function(e)
{
    var first_name = $("#first_name").val() + " " + $("#last_name").val();
    var last_name = $("#first_name1").val() + " " + $("#last_name1").val();

    $("#priority option:first").html(first_name);
    $("#priority option:last").html(last_name);
});
```